# set globally absolute position to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, css-position

I am grabbing the position of an element using jquery's `.offset()` and then setting the div to be `position:absolute;` and setting it's `left` and `top` based off the information I got from `offset()`.

This works as long as all the element's parents are statically positioned since `position:absolute` is defined as

> "The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not
>   static) ancestor element"

So now I'm presented with 2 choices to fix this issue:

1. Somehow force the element to be positioned relative to the document. I don't see anything in the css spec that allows me to do this. (correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Instead of using `offset()`, use a function that grabs the element's position relative to its first positioned ancestor element. (I don't see any jQuery functions that do this. There is `position()` but that gets it relative to the element's parent).

How do I do either of these 2 options?

Comment: You could remove the node and reattach it to the body, making it relative to the document. Not ideal, but it'd allow you to position it correctly.

Comment: You can use position: fixed, but that'll *stick* the layers to their positions though. You can try what @Mathletics said, move the elements out of their parents into the body.

Comment: @Mathletics, add that as an answer, it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added comment as answer so you can accept:

Remove the node and reattach it to the body, making it relative to the document. Not ideal, but it'd allow you to position it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN actually just set left/top because that overrides that description. If you just leave it "absolute", it'll position itself as described: relative to the first static element before it. If you set left/top, it should position itself correctly.

The only time this is not true is if the parent element has a relative positioning. Then you're kind of screwed :/

Comment: Yeah that's what happened, the parent had a relative positioning =/